# Snake game: how to update positions in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, graphics

I had no experience with 2D arrays so I began experimenting in order to learn. One thing led to another, and I began to build the classic snake game. I am stuck on the process of adding the "tail", *i.e.*, placing a value in the 2D array, then having it mimic the movement of the "head" value when it traverses the array. I have tried a few things but nothing worth posting as they had no effect.

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/5ht4that/7/

And code snippet:

```js
var board = [];
var firstDraw = true;
var movement;
var direction = 'up';
var speed = 300;
var gameinprogress = false;

//Generate the 2d array that is the game board
function buildBoard() {
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //row
        var arr = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) { //column
            if (i === 0 || i === 49) { //if top or bottom
                arr[x] = 1;
            } else {
                if (x === 0 || x === 49) {
                    arr[x] = 1;
                } else if (firstDraw) {
                    if (x === 25 && i === 25) {
                        arr[x] = 2;
                        firstDraw = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    arr[x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        board.push(arr);
    }
    drawBoard();
}
//Draw the board from the 2d array
function drawBoard(){
    $('.food').remove();
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            if (board[i][x] === 2) {
                $('.board')
                    .append(
                    '<div id="head" class="border player" style="top: ' + 5 * i + 'px;' + 
                    'left: ' + 5 * x + 'px;"></div>');
            }
            if (board[i][x] === 3) {
                $('.board')
                    .append(
                    '<div class="border food" style="top: ' + 5 * i + 'px;' + 'left: ' + 5 * x + 'px;"></div>');
            }
        }
    }
}
//Randomly position food on the board
function drawfood() {
    $('.food').remove();
    row = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
    col = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);

    board[row][col] = 3;
}
//Move according to arrow keypress
function move() {
    var nextprop;
    for (i = 1; i < 49; i++) {
        for (x = 1; x < 49; x++) {
            var prop = board[i][x];
            if (prop === 2) {
                switch (direction) {
                    case 'left':
                        nextprop = board[i][x - 1];
                        board[i][x - 1] = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'up':
                        nextprop = board[i - 1][x];
                        board[i - 1][x] = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        nextprop = board[i][x + 1];
                        board[i][x + 1] = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'down':
                        nextprop = board[i + 1][x];
                        board[i + 1][x] = 2;
                        break;
                }
                if (nextprop === 1) {
                    reset();
                    $('.board').text('YOU LOSE');
                }
                if (nextprop === 3) {
                    drawfood();
                    if (speed > 100) speed -= 20;
                }
                board[i][x] = 0;
       $('.player').remove();
                drawBoard();
            }
        }
    }
}
//Reset game board
function reset() {
    gameinprogress = false;
    clearInterval(movement);
    board.length = 0;
    firstDraw = true;
    speed = 300;
    $('.player').remove();
    $('.food').remove();
    buildBoard();
    drawBoard(); 
}

/*
===================
Button Click Events
===================
*/
//Toggle start, stop button on click
$('#start, #stop').click(function () {
    $('#start, #stop').toggle();
});
//Start game (generate food, draw the board, and start movement)
$('#start').click(function () {
    gameinprogress=true;
    drawfood();
 drawBoard();
    movement = setInterval(function () {
        move('up');
    }, speed);
});
//Stop the game (reset the board, remove game lost text if there)
$('#stop').click(function () {
    $('.board').text('');
 reset();
});
//Check which arrow key was pressed, move accordingly
//if (direction === '___') break; implemented to prevent 'cheat' movement
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (!gameinprogress) return;
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
        case 37:
            if (direction === 'left') break;
            direction = 'left';
            clearInterval(movement);
            movement = setInterval(function () {
                move();
            }, speed);
            move();
            break;
        case 38:
            if (direction === 'up') break;
            direction = 'up';
            clearInterval(movement);
            movement = setInterval(function () {
                move();
            }, speed);
            move('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            if (direction === 'right') break;
            direction = 'right';
            clearInterval(movement);
            movement = setInterval(function () {
                move();
            }, speed);
            move();
            break;
        case 40:
            if (direction === 'down') break;
            direction = 'down';
            clearInterval(movement);
            movement = setInterval(function () {
                move('down');
            }, speed);
            move();
            break;
    }
});




/// Main
buildBoard();
drawBoard();
```

```css
.container {
    text-align:center;
    width:95%;
    height:95%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
.board {
    position:relative;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px  black solid;
}
.border {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.player {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.food {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='board'></div>
    <button id='start' type='button'>Start</button>
    <button id='stop' type='button' hidden>Stop</button>
</div>
```

The game grid might look like this:

```
var arr = [
    [0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,3,3,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

If I moved the first 3 value to the left so it would be at position [1][1] in the array, how then would I do a check, and move the second 3 value to position [1][2]? Keep in mind, the number of '3' values will continually grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you break down the snake into sections, each one of which keeps track of its position in the game grid. You can represent each section with an object. The whole snake is represented by an array of such objects.

Each section has to know at least two things:

- What is my current position in the grid?
- Which section am I following?

When you want to update the snake, you start at the head, which is the first section of the snake. It doesn't follow any other section. Next you look at the head's follower, then that section's follower, and so on until you reach the tail.

For each section, you want to answer the following question:

- What is my next position going to be?

For the head, the next position is determined by the user's key press (or lack thereof). For every other section, we have to consider what's going to happen to its leader, which is the section that it's following:

- If my leader is not moving anywhere, I will not move either.
- If my leader is moving to a new position, I will move to its current position.

It's important to avoid updating each section's position before you're done analyzing the whole snake. You have to perform two passes in each update cycle:

1. First pass: consider each section in order, starting from the head, and determine what its next position is going to be.
2. Second pass: update each section's position to the new position that you calculated in the first pass.

Below is a simple implementation of a snake that moves in response to user input. I think you'll be most interested in the `Game.moveSnake` function, which demonstrates the two-pass approach to updating the snake.

```js
var Game = {
  numRows: 12,
  numCols: 32,
  numSections: 10,
  cellSize: 13
};

Game.refreshDisplay = function () {
  var canvas = Game.canvas,
      context = Game.context,
      cellSize = Game.cellSize;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var snake = Game.snake,
      rgbHead = [70, 161, 52],
      rgb = rgbHead.slice(),
      numSections = Game.numSections;
  context.lineWidth = cellSize / 2;
  context.strokeStyle = '#acc9b2';
  for (var i = 1; i < numSections; ++i) {
    var section = snake[i],
        x = cellSize / 2 + section.c * cellSize,
        y = cellSize / 2 + section.r * cellSize;
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j += 2) {
      rgb[j] += Math.round((255 - rgb[j]) / 12);
    }
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + rgb.join(', ') + ')';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, cellSize / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  }
  var head = snake[0],
      x = cellSize / 2 + head.c * cellSize,
      y = cellSize / 2 + head.r * cellSize;
  context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + rgbHead.join(', ') + ')';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, cellSize / 1.6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
};

// The head wants to move from position (r, c) to position (r + dr, c + dc).
Game.moveSnake = function (dr, dc) {
  // Prevent the head from moving out of bounds.
  var snake = Game.snake,
      head = snake[0],
      numRows = Game.numRows, numCols = Game.numCols,
      nextR = head.r + dr, nextC = head.c + dc;
  if (nextR < 0 || nextR >= numRows || nextC < 0 || nextC >= numCols) {
    return;
  }
  // First pass: calculate each section's next position.
  head.nextR = nextR;
  head.nextC = nextC;
  var numSections = Game.numSections;
  for (var i = 1; i < numSections; ++i) {
    var section = snake[i],
        leader = section.leader;
    section.nextR = leader.r;
    section.nextC = leader.c;
    // Prevent the head from running over another snake section.
    if (head.nextR == section.nextR && head.nextC == section.nextC) {
      return;
    }
  }
  // Second pass: update each section's position.
  var grid = Game.grid,
      tail = snake[numSections - 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < numSections; ++i) {
    var section = snake[i];
    section.r = section.nextR;
    section.c = section.nextC;
  }
  Game.refreshDisplay();
};

window.onload = function () {
  // Prepare the game canvas.
  var container = Game.container = document.getElementById('grid'),
      canvas = Game.canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      context = Game.context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      numRows = Game.numRows,
      numCols = Game.numCols,
      cellSize = Game.cellSize;
  canvas.width = numCols * cellSize;
  canvas.height = numRows * cellSize;
  container.appendChild(canvas);
  var numSections = Game.numSections,
      snake = Game.snake = new Array(snake);
  // Initialize the head.
  snake[0] = {
    r: Math.floor(numRows / 2),
    c: Math.floor(numCols / 2)
  };
  // Make each successive section follow the previous one.
  for (var i = 1; i < numSections; ++i) {
    var leader = snake[i - 1];
    snake[i] = {
      leader: leader,
      r: leader.r,
      c: leader.c - 1
    };
  }
  $(window).keydown(function (event) {
    var code = event.which;
    if (code == 37 || code == 65) {
      Game.moveSnake(0, -1);
    } else if (code == 39 || code == 68) {
      Game.moveSnake(0, 1);
    } else if (code == 38 || code == 87) {
      Game.moveSnake(-1, 0);
    } else if (code == 40 || code == 83) {
      Game.moveSnake(1, 0);
    }
  });
  Game.refreshDisplay();
};
```

```css
#instructions {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}
#grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background: #ffe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="instructions">Click here, then press W-A-S-D or arrow keys to move the snake.</div>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to represent the snake somehow. E.g. [{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:2}]. When the snake moves, use push/shift or unshift/pop array methods to add new head position and optionally remove the tail position.
I think it is not a good idea to represent the snake additionally in the 2d map array, it brings no win.